Entity Framework Core error during scaffolding in .NET 8
I am trying to build an Azure Function app. To import my database context using EF Core, I am running the scaffolding command as shown below.
Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Persist Security Info=False;User ID = XXXX; Password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout = 30;' 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -Context Context -OutputDir ContextModels 
         -NoPluralize -Force

When I run this command from the PM console, I get this error:

System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AddImports.AbstractAddImportsService`4' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Method 'AddReplacements' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CaseCorrection.VisualBasicCaseCorrectionService' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
Method 'AddSyntacticClassifications' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Classification.VisualBasicSyntaxClassificationService' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
Method 'AddLexicalClassifications' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Classification.VisualBasicEditorClassificationService' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeGeneration.AbstractImportsAdder' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeGeneration.AbstractCodeGenerationService' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Derived method 'ConditionalAccessExpression' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CodeGeneration.VisualBasicSyntaxGenerator' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' cannot reduce access.

There is a lot more in the error, but I am limited by the amount I can post here. Hopefully this will be enough.
Can someone look at it and let me know what might be going on. I am using .NET 8 with the latest version of the packages that are available.

Libraries versions mismatch. Looks like improperly configured dependencies for VB project. Add project file packages references.

Maybe dotnet-ef should be updated.

I have 8.0.7 version of the entity framework core packages installed on my project. And  it is a C# project. So I am also confused by the VB references in the errors

Try to create fresh empty console application and try to check how it works.

Thank you Svyatoslav for your time in trying to help. Like I mentioned in my answer below, I had older dependencies and now it is fixed.

Looks like by default Microsoft.CodeAnalysis (4.5.0) installed only the 3.3.1 version of the dependencies. I updated all of them to 4.5.0 and now it works.
